# getting SIGNAL 11 error

Tags: android

Good day,

I have a question about developing applications for Android using SDK.
Our app faced an issue under Android 2.1 API Level 7 (at least under Android 2.1-update1 emulator and under Motorola Droid X 2.1 device).
It crashes and emulator shows in logcat only native error info about crash, without any java stack trace etc. After that app is trying to reload itself but crashes again. It works fine under Android 2.2 and 2.3.
Our users have Android 2.1 devices and get that problem.

```
INFO/DEBUG(28): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
INFO/DEBUG(28): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic/:2.1-update1/ECLAIR/35983:eng/test-keys'
INFO/DEBUG(28): pid: 230, tid: 239  >>> com.app <<<
INFO/DEBUG(28): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 8050927c
INFO/DEBUG(28):  r0 8000008b  r1 80000088  r2 80509278  r3 005091f0
INFO/DEBUG(28):  r4 afe38e08  r5 afe3b9bc  r6 0000a000  r7 00000001
INFO/DEBUG(28):  r8 4e592d80  r9 440f5db8  10 440f5da4  fp 0011fb90
INFO/DEBUG(28):  ip ad2338d4  sp 4e592ce8  lr afe0f3b0  pc afe0b060  cpsr 00000030
INFO/DEBUG(28):          #00  pc 0000b060  /system/lib/libc.so
INFO/DEBUG(28):          #01  pc 00014630  /system/lib/libnativehelper.so
INFO/DEBUG(28):          #02  pc 0000f1f4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
INFO/DEBUG(28): code around pc:
INFO/DEBUG(28): afe0b050 22016050 605a430a 4293e034 e18ed300
INFO/DEBUG(28): afe0b060 20016856 d1004206 2702e189 40351c3d
INFO/DEBUG(28): afe0b070 d0009506 483ce0ee 69851820 456246ac
INFO/DEBUG(28): code around lr:
INFO/DEBUG(28): afe0f3a0 e1a00005 e3a01001 e1a02004 ebfff980
INFO/DEBUG(28): afe0f3b0 e3500000 1a000001 ea000008 ebfff98a
INFO/DEBUG(28): afe0f3c0 e1a01004 e3a00002 ebfff985 e3500000
INFO/DEBUG(28): stack:
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592ca8  00000000
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592cac  afe0f2c0  /system/lib/libc.so
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592cb0  00000340
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592cb4  ad080c00  /system/lib/libdvm.so
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592cb8  ad080c00  /system/lib/libdvm.so
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592cbc  4a38c098  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/2 (deleted)
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592cc0  afe3bb74
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592cc4  afe0f3b0  /system/lib/libc.so
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592cc8  afe38e08  /system/lib/libc.so
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592ccc  005091f8  [heap]
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592cd0  00000003
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592cd4  000001b4
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592cd8  4e592d80
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592cdc  440f5db8
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592ce0  df002777
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592ce4  e3a070ad
INFO/DEBUG(28): #00 4e592ce8  4a38c0a8  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/2 (deleted)
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592cec  ad02e52b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592cf0  ad07ecc0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592cf4  ad02b3e7  /system/lib/libdvm.so
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592cf8  00000026
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592cfc  00000190
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592d00  00002bb4
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592d04  00000000
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592d08  00000002
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592d0c  ad02e489  /system/lib/libdvm.so
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592d10  0011fee8  [heap]
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592d14  00000001
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592d18  0000030c
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592d1c  ad214633  /system/lib/libnativehelper.so
INFO/DEBUG(28): #01 4e592d20  ad066a24  /system/lib/libdvm.so
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592d24  005091f8  [heap]
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592d28  00126778  [heap]
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592d2c  000002b4
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592d30  4a38c0a8  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/2 (deleted)
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592d34  000002b4
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592d38  4a324b90  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/2 (deleted)
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592d3c  4a480848  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/2 (deleted)
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592d40  4a38c098  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/2 (deleted)
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592d44  00000000
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592d48  000f41e8  [heap]
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592d4c  00043693  [heap]
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592d50  ad07ff50  /system/lib/libdvm.so
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592d54  4e592da0
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592d58  00000004
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592d5c  4000cf38  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/zygote/0 (deleted)
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592d60  440f5dd4
INFO/DEBUG(28):     4e592d64  ad00f1f8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
DEBUG/Zygote(30): Process 230 terminated by signal (11)
INFO/ActivityManager(61): Process com.app (pid 230) has died.
INFO/WindowManager(61): WIN DEATH: Window{49f36c78 com.app/com.app.core.Tabs paused=false}
INFO/WindowManager(61): WIN DEATH: Window{49f59388 com.app/com.app.activities.Game paused=false}
INFO/ActivityManager(61): Start proc com.app for activity com.app/.core.Tabs: pid=293 uid=10028 gids={3003}
DEBUG/ddm-heap(293): Got feature list request
INFO/UsageStats(61): Unexpected resume of com.app while already resumed in com.app
```

I tried to find an answer via google search, but did not get any good suggestions. It is very hard to understand what is the real cause of such error. How to debug and resolve that?

Thank you for feedback!
Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the signal 11 (SIGSEGV) and the following WIN DEATH after exiting a sound recording module with a TimerTask:

```
            micTimer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                int x = mediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.obj = x;
                mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            }
        }, 0, 100);
```

terminated with micTimer.cancel() in my stopRecording() method. It took some time to solve it. I had a hint from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973310/signal-11-sigsegv-crash-android-solved) and thought the equivalent of clearCache() in my case is micTimer.purge() after micTimer.cancel(). This solved the problem.

So I guess dependong on your context you need to clear a cache, purge a queue, recycle a bitmap, GC...

Comment: Hello guys....can you help me...I also got that log cat and my app is going crash .....In my app, I saving arraylist of drable into Database in blob and retrive it....I try your suggestion but can't success......You have any other clue.....?