# App working nicely on JB (and above) but silently crashing in ICS (and belov)

Tags: java, android

I wrote a metronome and used a KK phone for testing purpose during developement. Now that the app seems ready, I tested it on every Android/CyanogenMod version I could get on my test device (from GB to MM).
The app is reliable and can't be crashed by normal use on JB and newer but exhibit and strange behaviour on ICS and older (see belove). Since Android is retro compatible and the min-sdk=9 in manifest (and my app is only using lvl API 1) I looks weird to me.

**Details:**
I have a big start/stop button that toggle the main loop. The main loop produce the "tics" (through audioTrack) and is run in a separated task. A flag is used in the main activity to keep the current state (started or stopped) so that you can't "start" twice or "stop" twice, only do start/stop/start/stop/etc... cycles. The main loop, the task and the AudioTrack are set or unset accordingly.

**Problem:**
If I smash the start/stop several times in ICS (and older), app is closed *without* the Toast `The application Metronome as stopped unexpectidly etc...`.
Here is the logcat wich doesn't tell much to me:

```
<-- Application launched -->

I/ActivityManager(  247): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.arnaud.metronome/.Metronome bnds=[83,242][157,321] } from pid 347
D/dalvikvm(  247): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 205K, 45% free 4761K/8583K, external 2482K/2497K, paused 50ms
I/ActivityManager(  247): Start proc com.arnaud.metronome for activity com.arnaud.metronome/.Metronome: pid=919 uid=10045 gids={}
D/szipinf (  919): Initializing inflate state
D/dalvikvm(  919): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 47K, 51% free 2685K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 28ms
W/System.err(  919): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.arnaud.metronome/files/structures (No such file or directory)
W/System.err(  919):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)
W/System.err(  919):    at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.open(BlockGuard.java:232)
W/System.err(  919):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:80)
W/System.err(  919):    at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileInput(ContextImpl.java:432)
W/System.err(  919):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput(ContextWrapper.java:152)
W/System.err(  919):    at com.arnaud.metronome.StructureContainer.loadFromInternal(StructureContainer.java:201)
W/System.err(  919):    at com.arnaud.metronome.Metronome.onCreate(Metronome.java:81)
W/System.err(  919):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
W/System.err(  919):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
W/System.err(  919):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
W/System.err(  919):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
W/System.err(  919):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
W/System.err(  919):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err(  919):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
W/System.err(  919):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
W/System.err(  919):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err(  919):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
W/System.err(  919):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
W/System.err(  919):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
W/System.err(  919):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/InputMethodManager(  919): Ignoring onBind: cur seq=66, given seq=65
I/ActivityManager(  247): Displayed com.arnaud.metronome/.Metronome: +674ms

<-- Application fully launched. Commencing spamming the button -->

D/dalvikvm(  919): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 243K, 50% free 2841K/5575K, external 162K/543K, paused 16ms
D/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(  175): value of device and enable is 6 1
D/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(  175): msm_route_stream(PCM_PLAY, 5, 15, 1)
D/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(  175): addToTable (dec_id 5, dev_rx 6, dev_tx 65535, type 1, active 1)
D/dalvikvm(  919): GC_CONCURRENT freed 270K, 49% free 3010K/5831K, external 162K/543K, paused 3ms+2ms
D/dalvikvm(  547): GC_EXPLICIT freed 6K, 47% free 3350K/6279K, external 2481K/3099K, paused 26ms
D/dalvikvm(  919): GC_CONCURRENT freed 472K, 51% free 2973K/6023K, external 162K/543K, paused 1ms+2ms
D/dalvikvm(  919): GC_CONCURRENT freed 434K, 51% free 2973K/6023K, external 162K/543K, paused 2ms+2ms
D/dalvikvm(  919): GC_CONCURRENT freed 434K, 51% free 2973K/6023K, external 162K/543K, paused 2ms+2ms
D/dalvikvm(  919): GC_CONCURRENT freed 434K, 51% free 2974K/6023K, external 162K/543K, paused 2ms+3ms
D/dalvikvm(  919): GC_CONCURRENT freed 434K, 51% free 2974K/6023K, external 162K/543K, paused 2ms+2ms
D/dalvikvm(  919): GC_CONCURRENT freed 434K, 51% free 2974K/6023K, external 162K/543K, paused 2ms+2ms
D/dalvikvm(  919): GC_CONCURRENT freed 348K, 50% free 3060K/6023K, external 162K/543K, paused 2ms+2ms
D/dalvikvm(  919): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 434K, 53% free 2845K/6023K, external 162K/543K, paused 32ms
D/dalvikvm(  919): GC_CONCURRENT freed 173K, 49% free 3103K/6023K, external 158K/543K, paused 2ms+2ms
D/dalvikvm(  919): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 433K, 53% free 2888K/6023K, external 162K/543K, paused 18ms

<-- Crash start here -->

I/DEBUG   (  914): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (  914): Build fingerprint: 'SEMC/ST17i_1249-6227/ST17i:2.3.4/4.0.2.A.0.42/j_b_3w:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   (  914): pid: 919, tid: 932  >>> com.arnaud.metronome <<<
I/DEBUG   (  914): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 312e9000
I/DEBUG   (  914):  r0 312e9000  r1 00000080  r2 00000000  r3 317f1a50
I/DEBUG   (  914):  r4 312e9000  r5 312e9000  r6 00000000  r7 317f1a50
I/DEBUG   (  914):  r8 6904cb94  r9 ffffff92  10 00000000  fp 000003e8
I/DEBUG   (  914):  ip 690610bc  sp 317f1a18  lr 6fd11724  pc 6fd113fc  cpsr 200f0010
I/DEBUG   (  914):  d0  643a64696f72646e  d1  6472656767756265
I/DEBUG   (  914):  d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  914):  d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  914):  d6  0000000000000000  d7  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  914):  d8  000000003b9aca00  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  914):  d10 3fb8129d00000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  914):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  914):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  914):  d16 0000000000000000  d17 3ff0000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  914):  d18 3fc5555555555549  d19 bf4b3f057997ac2a
I/DEBUG   (  914):  d20 3e707186c2887fc1  d21 be5ae5839fe26830
I/DEBUG   (  914):  d22 bc5abb2580000000  d23 3de5d93a5acfd57c
I/DEBUG   (  914):  d24 0000000000000000  d25 ffffffffffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  914):  d26 0000000000000000  d27 ffffffffffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  914):  d28 0100010001000100  d29 4049000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  914):  d30 4049000000000000  d31 3ff0000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  914):  scr 20000010
I/DEBUG   (  914): 
I/DEBUG   (  914):          #00  pc 000113fc  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_mutex_lock)
I/DEBUG   (  914):          #01  pc 00011720  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative)
I/DEBUG   (  914):          #02  pc 0002d7b8  /system/lib/libmedia.so
I/DEBUG   (  914): 
I/DEBUG   (  914): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   (  914): 6fd113dc e3a02001 ebfffe82 e1a00005 e8bd87f0 
I/DEBUG   (  914): 6fd113ec 00035fc4 e92d47f0 e2504000 0a000019 
I/DEBUG   (  914): 6fd113fc e5946000 e5947000 e2166903 1a000017 
I/DEBUG   (  914): 6fd1140c e5945000 e1a02004 e2055a02 e1a00005 
I/DEBUG   (  914): 6fd1141c e3851001 ebffed67 e3500000 13856002 
I/DEBUG   (  914): 
I/DEBUG   (  914): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   (  914): 6fd11704 e1a03007 e1a02006 e2011001 e1a00004 
I/DEBUG   (  914): 6fd11714 ebfffd9a e1a04000 e1a00005 ebffff32 
I/DEBUG   (  914): 6fd11724 e374006e 03a0006e 13a00000 e8bd81f0 
I/DEBUG   (  914): 6fd11734 e304cdd3 e3043240 e92d4010 e341c062 
I/DEBUG   (  914): 6fd11744 e1a0e002 e24dd008 e340300f e1a0200d 
I/DEBUG   (  914): 
I/DEBUG   (  914): stack:
I/DEBUG   (  914):     317f19d8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  914):     317f19dc  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  914):     317f19e0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  914):     317f19e4  0000ee6b  
I/DEBUG   (  914):     317f19e8  0000ee6b  
I/DEBUG   (  914):     317f19ec  6fd0fe54  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (  914):     317f19f0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  914):     317f19f4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  914):     317f19f8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  914):     317f19fc  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  914):     317f1a00  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  914):     317f1a04  3b9aca00  
I/DEBUG   (  914):     317f1a08  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  914):     317f1a0c  3b9aca00  
I/DEBUG   (  914):     317f1a10  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  914):     317f1a14  6904cb94  /system/lib/libmedia.so
I/DEBUG   (  914): #00 317f1a18  ffffff92  
I/DEBUG   (  914):     317f1a1c  312e9000  
I/DEBUG   (  914):     317f1a20  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  914):     317f1a24  317f1a50  
I/DEBUG   (  914):     317f1a28  6904cb94  /system/lib/libmedia.so
I/DEBUG   (  914):     317f1a2c  ffffff92  
I/DEBUG   (  914):     317f1a30  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  914):     317f1a34  6fd11724  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (  914): #01 317f1a38  312e9000  
I/DEBUG   (  914):     317f1a3c  312e9004  
I/DEBUG   (  914):     317f1a40  317f1af0  
I/DEBUG   (  914):     317f1a44  fffffffe  
I/DEBUG   (  914):     317f1a48  6904cb94  /system/lib/libmedia.so
I/DEBUG   (  914):     317f1a4c  6902d7bb  /system/lib/libmedia.so
D/dalvikvm(  919): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 434K, 53% free 2888K/6023K, external 162K/543K, paused 31ms
D/dalvikvm(  919): GC_CONCURRENT freed 173K, 52% free 2931K/6023K, external 158K/543K, paused 2ms+12ms
I/BootReceiver(  247): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_00 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
W/AudioTrack(  919): obtainBuffer timed out (is the CPU pegged?) 0x17c230 user=00010554, server=000079e0
I/DEBUG   (  914): debuggerd committing suicide to free the zombie!
I/DEBUG   (  944): debuggerd: Jun 15 2012 20:09:09
D/dalvikvm(  247): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 533K, 43% free 4922K/8583K, external 870K/1382K, paused 33ms
I/WindowManager(  247): WIN DEATH: Window{2b270d18 com.arnaud.metronome/com.arnaud.metronome.Metronome paused=false}
I/ActivityManager(  247): Process com.arnaud.metronome (pid 919) has died.
D/Zygote  (  174): Process 919 terminated by signal (11)

<-- App is closed here, We are now back to the launcher -->

W/InputManagerService(  247): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 919 uid 10045
D/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(  175): AudioStreamOutMSM72xx::standby()
D/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(  175): Deroute pcm out stream
D/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(  175): deleteFromTable, type 1
D/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(  175): updateDeviceInfo: E rx_device 6 and tx_device 11
D/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(  175): No active voicecall/playback, disabling cur_rx 6
D/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(  175): value of device and enable is 6 0
D/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(  175): No active voicecall/recording, disabling cur_tx 11
D/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(  175): value of device and enable is 11 0
D/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(  175): updateDeviceInfo: X cur_rx 6 cur_tx 11
```

I am trying to subscribe to f-droid and could update the gitlab if someone wants to have a closer look.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777767/getting-signal-11-error,  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/mIwL4nHNYfw  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/o9_xt7pQzUk  Perhaps the process is getting killed on that device and not others, and it isn't actually related to OS version.  What happens if you test on emulators with various versions?

Comment: My computer (2Go core2duo) can't handle emulator. I am developping in a VM Debian jessie with 1Go for RAM. From your links, I guess my problem might be related to some AsyncTask or AudioTrack not being released fast enough by the GC (maybe)... I would love to try it on another device. I will investigate de /proc/cpuinfo

Comment: You might also be able to use a test service.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/  https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/