# How to fix signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR) error?

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, heap-corruption

I am trying to parse corrupt **.EMF** image file.After successfully parsing and attempting to construct the image using Picture(android.Graphic) getting the ***Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000004 (code=1)*** error.

I searched on net and found that this is memory exception and also attempted the fix suggested by them [fix1](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html), [fix2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250951/jni-bitmap-operations-for-helping-to-avoid-oom-when-using-large-images/18250952?noredirect=1)[*recycle bitmap*].There are lot of question related to this in Stackoverflow but nothing solve my problem.

And image size is around kb only.Is there any way to validate or check the .EMF file.

**Platform**:
4.2 & above

**Devices**:
Nexus 7.

Comment: Better is check whether EMF image file is corrupted before do anything

Comment: We also face this issue on Nexus 7 with PLatform 4.4. This is not necessarily due images big in size but also if you are working with socket connections (in our case) or function call being made from two different threads at the same time. You can check these 2 links for same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023291/fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x00000000-code-1-phonegap, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662446/invalid-heap-address-and-fatal-signal-11/11812665#11812665

Comment: @TGMCians  : checked and EMF file is parsing correctly but error still continues in 4.2 & above platform.

Comment: @KanakSony: Ya but don't how to exactly trace the issue.Any suggestions to find the cause of the error.