# Cordova File Transfer Crashes app

Tags: android, cordova, file-transfer, cordova-plugins

I'm on cordova 3.4.0 building on Android, and I'm aiming to download a file and open it with an intent. I'm stuck on the downloading bit as it tombstones soon after apparently downloading the file.

The plugins are installed and permissions are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I also have an application line with:

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

The code is:

```
    downloadFile: {

    run: function(uri, fileName, folderName) {

        var that = this;

        filePath = "";

        that.getFilesystem(
            function(fileSystem) {
                console.log("gotFS");

                if (APP.isAndroid()) {
                    that.getFolder(
                        fileSystem,
                        folderName,
                        function(folder) {
                            filePath = folder.toURL() + "\/" + fileName;
                            console.log("FILE PATH :::: " + filePath);
                            that.transferFile(uri, filePath);
                        }, function() {
                            console.log("failed to get folder");
                        }
                    );
                }
                else {
                    filePath = fileSystem.root.fullPath + "\/" + fileName;
                    that.transferFile(uri, filePath);
                }
            },
            function() {
                console.log("failed to get filesystem");
            }
        );
    },

    getFilesystem:function (success, fail) {
        window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, success, fail);
    },

    getFolder: function (fileSystem, folderName, success, fail) {
        fileSystem.root.getDirectory(folderName, {create: true, exclusive: false}, success, fail)
    },


    transferFile: function (uri, filePath) {
        var transfer = new FileTransfer();
        console.log("Trying to DL  : : " + encodeURI(uri) + " to " + filePath);
        /** **/
        transfer.download(
            encodeURI(uri),
            filePath,
            function (entry) {
                console.log("TRYING TO OPEN FILE ::: " + entry.toURL());
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
            }
        );
    }
},
```

.....

```
this.downloadFile.run(url, "file_name.pdf", "pdfs");
```

This seems to download the file which then tombstones like so, after occasionally reaching the success callback.
:

```
    I/chromium(26125): [INFO:CONSOLE(388)] "TRYING TO OPEN FILE ::: cdvfile://localhost/persistent/fileName", source: file:///android_asset/www/app/env.js (388)
F/libc    (26125): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 26203 (GAThread)
I/DEBUG   (  269): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (  269): Build fingerprint: 'motorola/falcon_asia_ds/falcon_umtsds:4.4.2/KXB20.25-1.31/14:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   (  269): Revision: 'p3c0'
I/DEBUG   (  269): pid: 26125, tid: 26203, name: GAThread  >>> nz.co.forsythbarr.mobileapp <<<
I/DEBUG   (  269): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
D/WifiStateMachine( 1010): handleMessage: E msg.what=151572
D/WifiStateMachine( 1010): processMsg: ConnectedState
D/WifiStateMachine( 1010): processMsg: L2ConnectedState
I/DEBUG   (  269):     r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 625ca245  r3 00000028
I/DEBUG   (  269):     r4 00000008  r5 625ca246  r6 00000000  r7 ffffffff
I/DEBUG   (  269):     r8 00000001  r9 40b59130  sl 00000028  fp 625ca245
I/DEBUG   (  269):     ip 6402fb34  sp 64a39990  lr 64024105  pc 40b440f6  cpsr 600f0030
I/DEBUG   (  269):     d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  269):     d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  269):     d4  3268053561342f79  d5  796470730830312d
I/DEBUG   (  269):     d6  64707306312e332f  d7  7074746808332f79
I/DEBUG   (  269):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  269):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  269):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  269):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
```

.....

Would appreciate any ideas as to how to fix.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973310/signal-11-sigsegv-crash-android).

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? I am also having a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

Another cause could be if you're using CrossWalk (a replacement browser plugin) that has a different cookie API, which the FileTransfer plug-in doesn't know. Fix at https://github.com/gaochun/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/commit/0063249e279b99a0feb4601650fc3a4c9e8a8ed2?diff=split .